# meaning of Your odds of survival are reduced

Tags: meaning, idioms

I know "Low odds" means something is likely, and "high odds" means something is unlikely. But in this sentence, "your odds of survival are greatly reduced" is confusing. Does it mean I am more likely to live or die?

> Now, we're all aware that an early diagnosis that is accurate is critical for survival. The problem is that many cancer diagnostic tools are invasive, costly, often inaccurate and they can take an agonizing amount of time to get the results back. Still worse, when it comes to some forms of cancer, such as ovarian, liver or pancreatic cancer, good screening methods simply don't exist, meaning that often people wait until physical symptoms surface, which are themselves already indicators of late-stage progression. Like a tornado strike in an area without an early warning system, there is no alarm to warn, for the danger is already at your doorstep **when your odds of survival are greatly reduced**. Having the convenience and accessibility of regular screening options that are affordable, noninvasive and could provide results much sooner, would provide us with a formidable weapon in the fight against cancer.

New nanotech to detect cancer early
https://www.ted.com/talks/joshua_smith_new_nanotech_to_catch_cancer_early

Comment: Which is better:  Odds of surviving a traffic accident being 1 in 10 or 9 in 10?  Which is lower?

Comment: @HotLicks Because low odds means something is more likely, lower odds must be 9/10. So in this sentence, does it mean you are more likely to survive? I guess the speaker was confused between short odds and long odds.

Comment: That's a very peculiar sentence, no matter what the intended meaning.

Comment: *Low odds* normally means *unlikely*. The opposite is better expressed as *high chances*.

Comment: @Lawrence  No, please check: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/high-odds-or-low-odds

Comment: That’s talking about ‘betting’ odds, which are said to be expressed as [odds against](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds). The odds *in favour of* something happening or the odds *for* an outcome are expressed the other way. If you said something had high or low odds, it would normally be understood to refer to the odds *of* that happening, not the odds *against* that happening. The quote uses the phrase *odds **of** survival*, which definitely conveys the sense of *low=>unlikely*.

Comment: @Lawrence Omg so confusing. Thanks a lot!! I got it now.

Comment: Mango, did you notice how long that sentence was, and how little of it matters?

Your horse or jockey overeats and their odds of winning are greatly reduced.

Please be aware that “your odds of survival are greatly reduced” is confusing precisely because low and high odds can mean exactly the same thing, depending on your perspective.

That your book-maker offers low odds doesn’t mean the chances are low; it means the chances are high.